# Issues with sending emails using an smtp server in python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtp, gmail

I am trying to create an email spammer. I know is is frowned upon but i am running into problems which i cannot seem to solve. I cannot seem to figure out how to:

1. Define a variable containing a **list** of emails and add each of them to the recipients list.
2. Send an email from the google smtp server to that list of emails defined previously.

```
import smtplib
from email import message



sent = int(0)
while (True):
    sent = sent + 1
    from_addr = 'email@gmail.com' # Must be a gmail adress as the gmail smtp server is used
    to_addr = ['email@email.com', 'email2@email.com']
    subject = 'test!'
    body = 'test!'

    msg = message.Message()
    msg.add_header('from', from_addr)
    for n in len(to_addr):
        msg.add_header('To') = ', '.join(to_addr[n]) # Add all entries from to_addr as recipients
    msg.add_header('subject', subject)
    msg.set_payload(body)

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.login(from_addr, 'insertyourpasswordhere') # This will also generate an error!
    server.send_message(msg, from_addr=from_addr, to_addrs=[to_addr])
    server.quit()
```

*I don't want the program to send an email to one user in the list at once, i want it to add them all as recipients and then send the email to all of them.*

**For this code to even have the chance at working, you need to have less safer apps enabled on your gmail account**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the following steps for use gmail's server to send mail:

1. Turn on the less secure apps
2. You'll get the security mail in your gmail inbox, Click Yes,it's me in that.
3. Now run your code again.

**NOTE**:Before performing code to required start TLS for security.

```py
import smtplib 
from email.message import EmailMessage
sent = int(0)
while (True):
    sent = sent + 1
    from_addr = 'gmail@gmail.com'
    to_addr = ['gmail1@gmail.com', 'gmail2@email.com']
    subject = 'test!'
    body = 'test!'

    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.add_header('from', from_addr)

    msg.add_header('To',', '.join(to_addr))
    msg.add_header('subject', subject)
    msg.set_payload(body)
    # creates SMTP session 
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) 

    # start TLS for security 
    server.starttls() 
    # Authentication 
    server.login(from_addr, 'insertyourpasswordhere') 

    # sending the mail 
    server.send_message(msg, from_addr=from_addr, to_addrs=', '.join(to_addr))

    # terminating the session 
    server.quit()
```

***You change only email and password, above script will run successfully!!***